# Methods, Objects to create currency converter in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods

This is going to be a long one.  I have an assignment I have been working on and I have been having issues.  I have a ton of code and I am not quite sure how to get it to function properly if at all with what I am trying to do.  I will post the sections and maybe some of you can see that I am trying to keep this in JavaScript only and not jQuery or pHp or anything else, keep seeing that as responses.

First part: html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Currency Converter 2.0</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="currency.css">
<script src="currency1.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Currency Converter</h1>
<p>Enter Dollar Amount</p>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="currencyTextInput" size="40" placeholder="For example 12.12">
  <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="Enter">
</form>
<ul>
  <li id="money0"></li>//these names are not final,
  <li id="money1"></li>//I know i will need to change them
  <li id="money2"></li>
  <li id="money3"></li>
  <li id="money4"></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

second part: .js file

```
window.onload = function () {
var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}

var exchangeRate = []; 
//this will be later one in the code, but aiming to have data pushed in here from objects

function handleButtonClick(e) {
var textInput = document.getElementById("currencyTextInput");
var moneyString = textInput.value;
var parsedMoney = parseFloat(moneyString);
var valid = !isNaN(parsedMoney);

if (!valid) {
        alert("Please, enter a valid number");
} else {
    //planning on using this part to list my results in a bullet list   
}
e.preventDefault();
}
```

So with testing that part works with my html code, minus the else.
the rest of my code with my methods.  this is where I am having issues.  I can do one method and have it work, but I have 5 that I am to get the info from.

```
function GetCurrency(name, cRate) {
this.name = name;
this.c_rate = c_rate;
this.convert = function(usd) {
   cRate * currencyTextInput  //not sure if this will grab that info or not
return //haven't the slightest idea where to send this data
}
}

var e_u = {
name: "European Euro",
cRate: 0.77334,
convert: function() {
   cRate * currencyTextInput
return exchangeRate.push(exchangeRate())//not sure if this is possible or do I need
}                                       //to assign an array slot for it
};

var u_k = {
name: "British Pound Sterling",
cRate: 0.66202,
convert: function() {
   cRate * currencyTextInput
return exchangeRate.push(exchangeRate())
}
};

var india = {
name: "Indian Rupee",
cRate: 55.7155,
convert: function() {
   cRate * currencyTextInput
return exchangeRate.push(exchangeRate())
}
};

var aus = {
name: "Australian Dollar",
cRate: 1.02931,
convert: function() {
   cRate * currencyTextInput
return exchangeRate.push(exchangeRate())
}
};

var japan = {
name: "Japanese Yen",
cRate: 102.063,
convert: function() {
   cRate * currencyTextInput
return exchangeRate.push(exchangeRate())
}
};
```

Basically, trying to have the user enter a number, validate that, then display that number (which will be usd) and multiply by each conversion rate and then display the results and the country/currency associated with the result in an ordered bullet list.  Hopefully that is possible with what I have or is possible to do.  I am just not sure how to push method data to an array and I need 2 bits of info from each. This is so aggravating, beginning web programming class my ass.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an assignment, I will only point you in the right direction.

First off combine all your currency data into one array, then you can process it much more easily, in addition adding a new currency should require you to add it to this table and nothing else! :

```
  var currencies = [
    {name: "Australian Dollar", rate: 1.02931 },
    {name: "Indian Rupee", rate: 55.1755 }
   // ... etc
  ];
```

Now add an event handler to trigger when the dollar amount changes or the convert button is clicked. In that handler create a new array with the corresponding currency values :

```
  var conversions = currencies.map (function (c) {
    return '<li>' + c.name + ' : ' + c.rate * dollarValue + '</li>';
  });
```

`dollarValue` is, of course, the value you got from the users input. make sure it is a number. Instead of `map` you could use a `for` loop to process the currency array. Note I have wrapped each conversion in a `<li>` `</li>` ready for insertion into the HTML

Find the `ul` for your results using `document.getElementById` and replace its contents with the results calculated above:

```
  document.getElementById ('results').innerHTML = conversions.join ('');
```

In you HTML, the `<ul>` will be empty at first.

That's it. Should not be more than about 20 lines of JS in total.

If you get stuck, post a new question with your new code and why it does not work. Add a comment here so I will be alerted to your new question.